# Access JavaScript function in a programatically iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to access a JavaScript function in a programatically created iFrame from a JavaScript function outside. I tried several ways, but was not successful. L ike `window.frames['frameid']`, etc.

Could you please provide me the correct syntax?

Comment: Do both the frame page and the parent page reside on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more appropriate example based on your comments ;)

The main page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
    <script>
        var receiver = {
          listen:function(msg){
            alert(msg);
          }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The iframe page: *iframe.html*, but can be a JSP with similar output

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>iframe page</title>
    <script src="external.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- some content here -->
    <script>
        externalFunction('hello', window);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JS file: *external.js*

```
function externalFunction(msg, w){
    w.parent.receiver.listen(msg);
}
```

Place those 3 files in the same directory and open the main page.
You should get a popup with "hello".

Comment: Actually, I am using ExtJS framework. I have a JSP inside an iFrame, I would like to call the javascript functions in the JSP from the a javascript function outside which is basically in a JS file. Would the options you mentioned would work? Please clarify me.

Comment: I would make the reverse, when the JSP is loaded, call an object of the parent. To do that, add a script tag at the very end of the BODY tag. And in this script add a command like parent.receiver.listen(msg). The object "receiver" must exist as a global object, and have a function "listen" and "msg" is a parameter you send to that function.

Comment: Mic, I have added a function in the parent JS file as, 
var receiver = {listen:function(){ alert('parent'); } }
And added -- parent.receiver.listen(); in the script tag of the BODY tag in the JSP. 
From the parent JS file, I have a button onClick calling a function listen. But, it does not seem to work. Please let me know, if I am doing as you mentioned.
But, I would like to call a function 'test' in the JSP from outside.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: scraped the previous answer with another example

Comment: Mic,Apologize if I had confused you. I have func1() in JSP which is rendered as an iFrame in ExtJS window. And I have a button on the exterior panel on the ExtJS window,which is basically outside the iFrame. When I click on the button I am unable to call func1() function in the iFrame (JSP). Please note, the extjs iFrame is created programatically. I tried several options like window.frames[frameid] to get handle of iFrame, but could not get it. All I would request is access function in JSP from outside. Appreciate your help.

Comment: make the msg = {callBack:func1} when you call w.parent.receiver.listen(msg); and in the receiver.listen, enable the button and call msg.callBack at the onclick event

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are in the same domain. Actually, I am using ExtJS framework. I have a JSP inside an iFrame, I would like to call the javascript functions in the JSP from the a javascript function outside which is basically in a JS file.